# "Prefix free" isn't pre-fixing image filters...?

Tags: css, prefixfree

I'm trying to use "Prefix free" (http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) on image filters and it seems the script isn't adding a -webkit- prefix to it.

Here's the example: http://codepen.io/barkins/pen/ByeGjd

```
img {
  filter: sepia(.5);
}
```

Shouldn't "Prefix free" add "-webkit- to the style? So it would look something like this:

```
img {
  filter: sepia(.5);
  -webkit-filter: sepia(.5);
}
```

Thanks advance for any help in advance.

Comment: umm...where is `prefixfree.js` included in the codepen? I don't see it anywhere...

Comment: Click on the little "gear" icon next to CSS heading. It should be selected there.

Comment: It should be, but I don't see it either.

Comment: If you [look through the source](https://github.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree/blob/gh-pages/prefixfree.js) and [try the interactive demo](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/#test-drive), `sepia()` doesn't appear to be supported by the script.

Comment: Interesting. That is too bad.